# How to find the last element inside same divs in selenium python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to find the last element inside a div, print it to the console and wait for the next one to generate, using selenium. I have tried for and while loops but they do not work. also, it selects only the first one. I want to select every time the last one.

In the example below:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            This is the first text
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            This is the second text
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to find every time `This is the second text` and if generates another `This is the third text` and so on. I have tried this, but it does not work. `myText = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col']").text`

Please at least pseudo code for this loop in python.

How to write a simple python code for this which gets the last text and prints it to the console. and then waits until another one generates and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all the elements in a list using xpath and then fetch the last element from that list using `[-1]` index of that list.
You can do it like:

```
# Fetching all the elements in a list
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col']")))
text_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col']")  

# Fetching the text of last element
last_text = text_list[-1].text
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @AayushKhawaja have edited my ans, please check now

Answer (score 1):

To find last element with CSS selector use :last-child in your case
'div[class="col"] :last-child' https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

With Xpath you can use this selector [last()] to get last element 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: I have added the code and I want the code to run this forever. @RSM

Comment: @AayushKhawaja for it to run forever,you could use javascript id explain if youre intrested or you want a purely python code?

Comment: @AaryanshSahay Anything can help. I just want to achieve what I want. but better to do it in python. Please have a look at my code above, it only selects the first element. I want to select the last one.